# How to integrate upi and tez payments in app like bookmyshow and flipkart did using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, upi, google-tez

In my app I am going to transaction through upi so I want integrate upi paments like how flipkart and bookmyshow did. What is the procedure to do it ? Can anyone help

Comment: Refer this https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-integrate-UPI-into-my-website-application

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to approach banks for that. As only banks are permitted to have access to it. You can act as a front-end PSP (payment system provider) and issue UPI services to customers. For this, you need a sponsor bank, live with UPI. Currently, only banks are allowed to directly access UPI frameworks.